# Write csv file to S3 Bucket without storing it locally

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Before I used to create a .csv file and store it in a local system where the application is running and then I used to send it to AWS S3 Bucket.

Now I don't want to create any file on the application side. I want to write my data to S3 Bucket as a .csv file directly, Is it possible?
                     If possible please guide me the way I can do this.

Comment: Not sure if that's possible. S3 is object storage, not file storage. So you can't "open" a file in it and start appending lines. Maybe you can mount int as a filesystem with fuse https://medium.com/tensult/aws-how-to-mount-s3-bucket-using-iam-role-on-ec2-linux-instance-ad2afd4513ef

Comment: I know that S3 is object storage.I don't know who downvoted my question but there is a way to write our Data in the S3 bucket in a .csv file. We just need to send our data as InputStream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There is a way to achieve this, we have to send our data as InputStream** 
In my case, I did these changes:
[1]I updated my Bean class to Override toString() method as follows

```
public class Employee{
String Id;
String employeeNo; 
String name;
//get and set

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "{"+ Id +","+ employeeNo + ","+ name + "}";
}
```

[2]I took the list of data and converted into List<String[]>

```
List<Employee> employeeList=//get employee list
List<String[]> csvData = toStringArray(employeeList);
```

My toStringArray() will return List<String[]>

```
private List<String[]> toStringArray(List<Employee> employeeList) {
List<String[]> records = new ArrayList<String[]>();
// adding header to csv
records.add(new String[] { "EmployeeId", "EmployeeNo", "Name"});
// add data to csv
Iterator<Employee> emp = employeeList.iterator();
while (emp.hasNext()) {
Employee data = emp.next();
records.add(new String[] { emp.getId(), emp.getEmployeeNo(), emp.getName() });
}
return records;
}
```

[3] Now I converted this data to String

```
String strCsvData=writeCsvAsString(csvData);
```

my writeCsvAsString() method is

```
 public String writeCsvAsString(List<String[]> csvData) {
        StringWriter s = new StringWriter();
        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(s);
        writer.writeAll(csvData);
        try {
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        String finalString = s.toString();
        logger.debug("Actual data:- {}", finalString);
        return finalString;
  }
```

Now I converted this String into InputStream and I send this to S3 bucket with contentType metadata **"text/csv"**

```
InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(strCsvData.getBytes());
```